# Missing Insert Record on the table with Trigger (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

**The scenario is the following -**

1. OrderTable with Columns "OrderId" and "OrderType"
2. OrderRelationTable with Columns "OrderId" and "CustId"
3. OrderProcessTable with Columns "OrderId", "OrderType", "CustId", and "ProcessFlag"

**The flow goes like this-**

Application1 creates the record in OrderTable -> Then pass the record to Application2 by using MQ protocol, Application 2 in this case insert/create the record passed in the OrderRelationTable -> Then a trigger is called in Oracle DB to create the record in OrderProcessTable

**Problem**

Sometimes the record is not inserted into table 3 OrderProcessTable. Not sure if it is cause by timing or there is something that is not correct with the trigger?

**Application1 Code**

```
    boolean updated = false;
    /** JDBC prepare statement execution insert into OrderTable in Java**/
    int rowCount = ps.executeUpdate();
    if(rowCount>0){
    updated=true;
    }
    log.log("updated flag:"+updated);
    /** I am able to see the log shows the flag is true, and recored inserted into OrderTable **/
```

**Application2 Code**
This doesn't really matter much assuming that it is some Java JDBC code that does the insert into OrderRelationTable and it is successful.

**The Trigger**

Assuming the syntax is correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERTINTOOrderProcessTable
AFTER INSERT ON OrderRelationTable
FOR EACH ROW DECLEAR
         v_order_type := null;
BEGIN
         SELECT OrderType INTO v_order_type FROM OrderTable
         WHERE OrderId = :new.OrderId
         AND OrderType IS NOT NULL
         AND rownum=1;

      IF v_order_type IS NOT NULL THEN
         INSERT INTO OrderProcessTable VALUES (:new.OrderId, v_order_type, :new.CustId, 'N');
      END IF;
END;
```

**Questions -**

1. After the Application 1 Code is executed is guaranteed DB will have the OrderTable record avaliable for SELECT statement? (Assume that updated flag is true)
2. Is there a timing issue with the app code and trigger? for example when trigger calls the SELECT statement from OrderTable? (of course the order id is matching in the OrderRelationTable and OrderTable)
3. Basically right now my problem is that sometimes (rarely) the record is not inserted into OrderProcessTable via the trigger even though it should (Order Type is not null)? Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked  OrderTable for OrderType IS NULL?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have checked the OrderTable OrderType is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

There's no *timing issue*, as far as I can tell.

As of trigger code: what is the purpose of `and rownum = 1` condition? I'm not saying that it is *wrong*, I'm just asking. Do you expect several rows to be returned by that query? If so, is that a legal situation? Wouldn't you rather handle it with the `WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception handler (i.e. instead of using the ROWNUM condition)?

What happens if SELECT returns nothing? It raises then `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception and trigger fails and certainly doesn't insert anything. Is it propagated so that someone (human being) or something (error logging procedure) sees / catches it so that you'd know that something went wrong?

And, of course, the fact that V_ORDER_TYPE remains NULL which causes INSERT to fail (as P. Salmon already suggested).

Comment: There can be multiple rows, However I only want to retrieve back 1 row because I only need 1 value. I have also added NO_DATA_FOUND exception. However in this case the data is there, so there is no way it would get to that exception.

Comment: OK, but - which "1 row"? If you don't care, ROWNUM is OK, I guess. If there's no way that NO_DATA_FOUND will ever be raised, you don't have to handle it (for example, just as testing whether a primary key column is NULL - can't be, as primary key columns are NOT NULL by default).

Comment: I don't really care about the rows, I just want to find out why rarely 1 of the record is not inserted into OrderProcessTable